# Using articles before noun phrases

Tags: articles, definite-article, zero-article

> Since the “Great Recession” of 2007-09, **the world’s major central banks** have kept **short-term interest rates** at **near-zero levels**. In the United States, even after the Federal Reserve’s recent increases, **short-term rates** remain below 1%, and **long-term interest rates** on **major government bonds** are similarly low. Moreover, **major central banks** have supported markets at a record level by buying up huge amounts of debt and holding it.

The questions:

- Why not the short-term interest rates?
- Why not the near-zero levels?
- Why not the long-term interest rates?
- Why not the major central banks?

Answer (score 1):

**Short-term interests rates** doesn't need an article because it's not talking about specific short-term interest rates since there is only one short-term interest rates. This is the same for **long-term interest rates**.

**Near-zero levels** doesn't need an article either there are no specific near-zero levels.

**Major centeral banks** doesn't need an article because there are no specific major central banks, just major central banks as a whole.

Comment: there is only one short-term interest rate." but it says short-term interest **rates**, you mean short-term interest rate is kind of a name? Lets say each bank got an employee called John, then we would say, "Since the “Great Recession” of 2007-09, the world’s major central banks have kept Johns at near-zero levels"?  "Major central banks" isn't this specific enough? Out of all the central banks we talk about one particular kind of banks, major banks.

Comment: @whowhenhow I meant **rates**, I fixed it now. As for the “major central banks”, there are no group A of major central banks and group B of major central banks.

Answer (score 0):

The first phrase needs an article because it is attached to a singular noun not a plural one.

In

> the world’s major central banks

the article "the" goes with "world".  It's only about the major central banks of one world!  It would be fine to say

> Since the “Great Recession” of 2007-09, major central banks

The other phrases are about plural nouns (levels, rates, banks). Plural nouns *can* be preceded by "the" but they don't have to be and "the" would change the meaning.